# I messed up my bios and now I can't get past password screen

Tags: bios, passwords

I have a Toshiba Satellite C75D.  My daughter downloaded ransomware and then she called the number that came up and allowed the ransomware hackers to access my computer and then neither of our Windows passwords would work.

I read about changing the bios from UEIF to CSM to change the windows password, so I decided to try this. I took an emergency boot disk and accessed the bios and changed the bios to boot from CD then USB then hard drive and changed UEIF to CSM and took secure boot off. I set up passwords for master in BIOS and an admin password. Both passwords were the same -- this way I could always access the computer?

But no when I turn on the computer a white with blue letters password screen immediately comes up but the password I set does not work and the screen shows verify error, continue; after I enter the password 3 times the computer shuts off. I really must have done something wrong when I changed the bios to boot from CD then USB then hard drive or when I changed it to CSM from UEIF and took secure boot off. I called Toshiba and they tell me I must have a virus and have to send the computer in, but they can't guarantee they can fix it. I have tried taking bios battery out, unplugging keyboard and touch pad and taking cd out and turning on, but nothing I do is working. Can anyone help me, as I feel so stupid?

Comment: Have you verified if the files on your drive are encrypted, typical SOP is for these Microsoft Support scam websites to, introduce EFS into the mix.  When that happens unless you pay sadly your files are gone, don't pay, restore from a backup

Comment: What happens if you put the BIOS settings back to how they were?

Comment: I can not put them back, as I can not access the bios now

Comment: ramhound, i am not trying to restore my files, i am trying to access bios to change back to default.  i have copies of my files, but i want to be able to use my computer, too

Comment: A pretty good windows password cracking software I know of is [Kon-Boot](http://getintopc.com/softwares/security/kon-boot-free-download/). You could try something like that to hack your own password.

Comment: Don't I need a bios password. I have to get past it before I can get to windows

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable doing this, you can open up the computer and remove the CMOS flat battery, and leave it off for a good few minutes so that it will forget settings. This usually will do the trick on most computers. No guarantee as I've also heard this method fail. On traditional desktop motherboards, there is also a jumper to reset CMOS (BIOS) settings, but you seem to have a laptop, so the battery may be your choice.

If this gets you past your password issue and you don't need to try and recover any files, just do a full HDD wipe and re install fresh everything.

Comment: I tried that; left battery out all day and everything unplugged and it did not work.

Comment: I would jumper it, but can not find the jumper on this computer and no internal schematic files are to be found.

Comment: Yea, sorry, you seem to have one of those PITA laptops. There are several suggested solutions on google, but I am afraid to suggest them to you as they are not the typical way to reset password. You could probably try what @Kiro Yakuza suggested. It's safer than trying to short something

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to find the jumper - even though I was told by Toshiba and local repair shop that there was not one.

After 3 tries it worked and a different screen asking for my HDD and SSD password came up. This time my password I had entered 100 times before worked and I was able to access my bios. Cannot figure out why it did not work before, but it had to be something messed up with BIOS.

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful to others if you explain *where* you found the jumper - even better if you can include a picture!